# Drop Pandas DataFrame lines according to a GropuBy property

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some DataFrames with information about some elements, for instance:

```
my_df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,12],[1,15],[1,3],[1,6],[2,8],[2,1],[2,17]],columns=['Group','Value'])
my_df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[1,7],[1,23],[2,6],[2,4]],columns=['Group','Value'])
```

I have used something like `dfGroups = df.groupby('group').apply(my_agg).reset_index()`, so now I have DataFrmaes with informations on groups of the previous elements, say

```
my_df1_Group=pd.DataFrame([[1,57],[2,63]],columns=['Group','Group_Value'])
my_df2_Group=pd.DataFrame([[1,38],[2,49]],columns=['Group','Group_Value'])
```

Now I want to clean my groups according to properties of their elements. Let's say that I want to discard groups containing an element with `Value`  greater than 16. So in `my_df1_Group`, there should only be the first group left, while both groups qualify to stay in `my_df2_Group`.

As I don't know how to get `my_df1_Group` and `my_df2_Group` from `my_df1` and `my_df2` in Python (I know other languages where it would simply be `name+"_Group"` with `name` looping in `[my_df1,my_df2]`, but how do you do that in Python?), I build a list of lists:

```
SampleList = [[my_df1,my_df1_Group],[my_df2,my_df2_Group]]
```

Then, I simply try this:

```
my_max=16
Bad=[]
for Sample in SampleList:
    for n in Sample[1]['Group']:
        df=Sample[0].loc[Sample[0]['Group']==n] #This is inelegant, but trying to work 
                                                #with Sample[1] in the for doesn't work
        if (df['Value'].max()>my_max):
            Bad.append(1)
        else:
            Bad.append(0)                      
    Sample[1] = Sample[1].assign(Bad_Row=pd.Series(Bad))
    Sample[1] = Sample[1].query('Bad_Row == 0')
```

Which runs without errors, but doesn't work. In particular, this doesn't add the column `Bad_Row` to my df, nor modifies my DataFrame (but the query runs smoothly even if `Bad_Row`column doesn't seem to exist...). On the other hand, if I run this technique manually on a df (i.e. not in a loop), it works.

How should I do?

Comment: what is your `myagg` function?  How do you get `my_df1_Group` from `my_df1`?

Comment: Oh, it's a rather  complicated collection of computations on the many columns my dfs actually has, even if I've only given one for simplicity. Let's say we start with elements dfs and group ones.

Comment: Are you trying to drop `my_df_Group['Group_Value']>16` or `my_df1['Value'] >16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment below, I think you are wanting to check if a `Group` in your aggregated data frame has a `Value` in the input data greater than 16.  One solution is to perform a row-wise calculation using a criterion of the input data.  To accomplish this, `my_func` accepts a row from the aggregated data frame and the input data as a pandas groupby object. For each group in your grouped data frame, it will subset you initial data and use boolean logic to see if any of the 'Values' in your input data meet your specified criterion.

```
def my_func(row,grouped_df1):
    if (grouped_df1.get_group(row['Group'])['Value']>16).any():
        return 'Bad Row'
    else:
        return 'Good Row'

my_df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,12],[1,15],[1,3],[1,6],[2,8],[2,1],[2,17]],columns=['Group','Value'])

my_df1_Group=pd.DataFrame([[1,57],[2,63]],columns=['Group','Group_Value'])

grouped_df1 = my_df1.groupby('Group')

my_df1_Group['Bad_Row'] = my_df1_Group.apply(lambda x: my_func(x,grouped_df1), axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
   Group  Group_Value   Bad_Row
0      1           57  Good Row
1      2           63   Bad Row
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work: I need to rule out a group (a row in `my_df1_Grouped`, in your example) having a ELEMENT (a row in `my_df1` with the same `Group` value than in `my_df1_Grouped`) which `Value` is over `max`.

Comment: @Matt see revised solution

Comment: Cheers, I've used your idea and I've been able to make everything work in my mock example. See my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Glad to hear it. Please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on dubbbdan idea, there is a code that works:

```
my_max=16
def my_func(row,grouped_df1):
    if (grouped_df1.get_group(row['Group'])['Value']>my_max).any():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

SampleList = [[my_df1,my_df1_Group],[my_df2,my_df2_Group]]


for Sample in SampleList:
    grouped_df = Sample[0].groupby('Group')
    Sample[1]['Bad_Row'] = Sample[1].apply(lambda x: my_func(x,grouped_df), axis=1)                     
    Sample[1].drop(Sample[1][Sample[1]['Bad_Row']!=0].index, inplace=True)
    Sample[1].drop(['Bad_Row'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```